# Algebra: how to rescale data with a log/exponential fit

Tags: math, algebra, bin, binning

I need to reorder data and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it.

```
(Int ((1- (([TD] - min)/( max - min)))*20))+1
```

This will take a number between 0-1  in [TD] (assuming max = 1 & min = 0) and break it into 20 integer codes (I need to be able to toggle the 20). Code 1 will be the top 5%, code 2 = 5-10% range- etc.

Put in .954 in for [TD], get a 1, put in .923, get a 2

Currently it breaks into even size bins, Can you rejigger so bins are broken up along log scale or some other exponential curve- see graph to see basic distribution pattern. Important: if you can solve, it needs to stay in same syntax so I can drop it into a particular program. The Int() function rounds down to the nearest integer, I couldn't find a 'round up' function so I'd like to keep using that. Thanks All,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably the "correct" way of setting up your bins in to use something like the inverse of the probability distribution of your data. In general, that's difficult to construct unless you know the statistical properties of your data.

Alternatively, if you know that your data are roughly distributed according to an exponentially decreasing distribution, then by taking the logarithm of each value you will make those transformed values more uniformly spaced. Those log-transformed values can then be binned using a recipe similar to your formula.

The following Python code illustrates the principle:

```
import numpy

x = 0.1 + numpy.random.exponential(size=(100000,))

nBins = 20
logX = numpy.log(x)
eps = 1e-9
minLogX, maxLogX = numpy.min(logX), numpy.max(logX)
bins = numpy.floor((nBins - eps) * (logX - minLogX) / (maxLogX - minLogX))
binCentres = numpy.exp(minLogX + (numpy.arange(0, nBins) + 0.5)
                                    * (maxLogX - minLogX) / nBins)
```

If we histogram the original data, `x`, using 20 bins this has most of the data in just a few bins:
[image]

If we compute the counts of the binned data after applying the log/exp transformation, we get a distribution like this (again using 20 bins):

[image]

This shows a much larger number of bins that have higher counts in the region where `x=1.5`, and shows an increasing separation between bins as `x` increases.